# Can I import a CSV file to livesql.oracle.com?

Tags: oracle, csv, import

**UPDATE:** I finally found a way to do the process I want. But I needed to first convert CSV file to .sql file from an external web and then uploaded the script to LIVE SQL and run the script. It worked smoothly and fulfilled my requirements.

I need to insert some values from a CSV file to database. Since I can't install Oracle into my laptop for not having requirements, I am using **Live SQL** (web version of Oracle DBMS) from Oracle. But It seems like I can't import any data from external files into the web version. Now, I want to know how I can import those data from csv files to my database table easily? Is there any way in LIVE SQL (possibly I didn't find any as I am a beginner) or any other way to proceed this?

Comment: instead of using livesql - if you want a true database experience, go to cloud.oracle.com and sign up for an Always Free Autonomous Database. then importing your CSV to a new or existing table is as easy as drag and drop

Comment: What requirements does your laptop not meet?  By using VirtualBox to create a vm, I've been installing Oracle EE under various OS's on consumer-class laptops for nearly 15 years.  Honestly, I can't imagine an oracle DBA _not_ having his own private database running under a vm on his own personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV file into a spreadsheet then if you have the columns `A`, `B` and `C` with data that is, respectively, a number, string and date data type then into the `D` column enter the formula:

```
="INSERT INTO your_table ( column1, column2, column3 ) VALUES ("&A1&", '"&B1&"', DATE '"&TEXT(C1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"');"
```

Copy/paste the formula down for all the rows.

Copy/paste the output of the D column into Oracle's LiveSQL.

*(Note: this assumes that the CSV file will not attempt any SQL injection. If it will then you will need to guard against it.)*